# Mysql pick/join multiple rows in one row

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT `a`.`department`, `a`.`category`, `a`.id, 
 (SELECT group_concat(t_0) FROM images WHERE ad_id=a.id) t_0,
 (SELECT group_concat(t_1) FROM images WHERE ad_id=a.id) t_1,
 (SELECT group_concat(t_1) FROM images WHERE ad_id=a.id) t_8 
 FROM `ads` AS `a`
 WHERE (a.department = 1) AND (a.category = 12) AND (a.charged=1) 
 ORDER BY `a`.`id` DESC
```

Is there better solution than this?
I need to have all images from images table for each a.id(ad_id)

Thanks :)

edit...

aha it seems this is working:

```
SELECT `a`.`department`, `a`.`category`, `a`.id, group_concat(t_0), group_concat(t_1), group_concat(t_8)
 FROM `ads` AS `a`
 LEFT JOIN images i ON i.ad_id=a.id
 WHERE (a.department = 1) AND (a.category = 12) AND (a.charged=1) 
 GROUP BY a.id DESC
```

Don't know if this is right solution thou... :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it's a good solution because you use [group_concat](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function and the function has the limit known as [group_concat_max_len](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len). Therefore it may happen that you won't get the whole result. Even if the limit is high I would rather not use the group_concat because you may move your application to another server and the settings may be different.

I would simply divide the query in simpler queries and process them in PHP (if it is your case). Premature optimazation is not good.

Comment: we don't know nothing about the application. maby there are only around 5 images or something?...
but theres another argument for your case. using group_concat just consumes more database time and application server time is usually more scaleable and a better trade off ;)

Comment: Thanks for comment! Well maybe there's 5 images BUT my experience is that every system complexity grows and therefore I would not write that in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

your second approach looks not so bad but it depends on the size of tables and the number of successful joins...
this will probably perform faster if you have a lot of imagse, but then you have only the images and have to link them to the other information in a second run:

```
select t_0,t_1,t_8,ad_id from images where ad_id is in (select id from ads  WHERE department = 1 AND category = 12 AND charged=1)
```

to sum it up if i understand your usecase correctly:
its better to first see which ads need to be displayed, and then fetch the images for exactly this ad without any joins!